# Reload content page after delete a object via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, events

I have a button and I want this to call a event via AJAX. This event is for delete a DB record so I want the content updated without the delete value/row. I think maybe I should put my code in the success of the .ajax call but my doubt goes to how to refresh the content? Do I need a second AJAX call to get the new content without the deleted value/row?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you fetch the data into the table?

Comment: @YairNevet using PHP and retrieve data using MySQL functions and SQL

Answer (score 3):

If you are using ajax then why are you refreshing page ? We use ajax to avoid page refresh. Still if u need it u can try add `window.location.reload();` function in your ajax.success() function. here is a example in case its useful to you http://www.amitpatil.me/ajax-table-adding-removing-rows-dynamically-using-javascript-animation/

Comment: @www-amitpatil-me Thanks I'm seeing your code right now but take a look at the latest comment to Dmytro in the post above, how to get this done using your code approach? Any suggestion?

Comment: In my case i am returning JSON data "{"success":"1","item_id":"1"}" in ur case just return "1" if record deletion successful or "0" if failed. and in success function check if responce is "1" then reload the page using "window.location.reload()" or "window.location.href=window.location.href"

Answer (score 2):

You can have it in the same call. In the `DELETE` script that the ajax call is pointing to just add on the query and send the data back using `json_encode()`. 
Then you simply update that specific area of the page.

Alternatively if you want to be lazy, after a success return from the ajax, simply do:

`window.location.reload();`

which will refresh the page.

Comment: If force page reloading for what AJAX than? :)

Comment: In this case you can do it without AJAX, page will reload in any case :) Why AJAX?

Comment: Because it is much easier to update and inform users with ajax, rather than doing the whole thing in php on page request and is a very easy way to stop the 'confirm resubmitting form' on clicking refresh. Like I said though it is a lazy option. But doing with ajax is STILL better!

Answer (score 2):

If you use AJAX for delete records than you don't need reload all page content (it's a goal of AJAX). In this case you must change you content with JavaScript DOM element removing.

If you delete some record with AJAX with some id you performe something like:

```
$("#deleteBtn").click(function() {

    // detect ID of the record (var id = ...)
    // call AJAX with post(...) or ajax(...)

    $("#id" + id).remove();  

});
```

Or better if you perform **remove()** function on AJAX result for more security and remove it only if your server side script really have delete the record from DB.

In my example assumed that you use **id** attribute of the your rows (or other HTML elements) for storing id of the record for access in future via $("#id" + id). You need some entry point for find your DOM element by record id.

Comment: By "perform remove() function on AJAX result" you mean in AJAX success event? Also yes I need to modify a bit my code to assign a id to each TR in my table so I can delete it on the fly using AJAX

Comment: Yes, on AJAX success you can find and remove needed DOM element.

Comment: @dmytro-zarazenko Ok, but I have another problem see the code here http://pastebin.com/FiyRWC6d I have two tables one for received messages and the other one for delivery messages so if I use your approach I will have problem because in first ids will be duplicated and second when the script look for id1 will find two id1 one for receive and one for delivery. I could change the things a bit and tell use id-receive-1 for received and id-delivery-1 for delivery but how to tell to my jQuery code which one to delete?

Comment: And you remove DB records in the same AJAX request? If yes, then you can simply send you script additional value, what you delete.

Comment: yes because exists to ways to delete one if I pick any check-box and second from within the message himself. If I use the first one then message_inbox[] or message_delivery[] will be an array and I know where to delete. If I use the second one then just pass the message ID to delete and perform the query by "WHERE message_id = id"

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, there are who ways of doing this.

1: wrap your rows in a container with the unique ID from the database row, and then use that ID to remove/hide the row that you just deleted from your page.

2: as you mentioned, you can fetch the data again and print it, but this won't be very efficient performance-wise.

/regards

Comment: Ok I assume that you and Dmytro are saying the same thing: change the content with Javascript DOM! Can any of both write a little sample using jQuery in how to get this done? I've a little experience but no so much :(